# Consultar Tabela no Access Através do R

Tags: r

Minha máquina é de 64 bit, gostaria de saber como faço para conectar o R a uma tabela no Access (2016).
Como exemplo para facilitar, suponha que a tabela no Access se chame `MAT` e o arquivo Access esteja em uma pasta no C:.
Grato.

Comment: Veja [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070706/how-to-connect-r-with-access-database-in-64-bit-window) do SO em inglês.

Answer (score 1):

Já tive um problema como esse e resolvi seguindo o o seguinte procedimento:
[Getting Access data into R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/getting-access-data-into-r/)

Basicamente, você precisará do pacote `RODBC`, que permitirá acessar uma variedade de banco de dados através ad conexão `ODBC`.

Não escrevi código na resposta pois achei desnecessário, já que o tutorial que sugeri está super completo e aborda, inclusive, como fazer a configuração da conexão `ODBC`.

Usei já faz um tempo, então pode ser que esteja desatualizado. Dê uma olhada na documentação do pacote também: [RODBC Documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf).

Espero ter ajudado!